# Make matrix of random integers

Tags: python, matrix, random

I need to write a function that takes the number of rows and columns and returns a matrix of a size `rows × columns` filled with random values between -10,10.

**need to be done without NumPy, Pandas and etc.

I write:

```
Mat = []

def mf(r,c):
    for i in range (0,c):
        Mat.append([])
    for i in range (0,r):
        for j in range (0,c):
            Mat[i].append(j)
            Mat[i][j]=0

    print(Mat)
mf(3,4)
```

How to insert random values in the range -10,10?

Any help, tips or solutions are greatly appreciated, I am a python beginner with a very basic knowledge.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `random` module to generate random integers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do this with the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html) module and a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> import random
>>> def randarray(r, c, lower=-10, upper=10, _randint=random.randint):
...     return [[_randint(lower, upper) for col in range(c)]
...             for row in range(r)]
... 
>>> randarray(3, 2)
[[-1, -5], [-7, -8], [8, 7]]
>>> randarray(4, 2)
[[9, 1], [7, 5], [-1, -3], [-7, 9]]
```

The reason for using `_randint=random.randint` in the signature is that it binds that function to a name that is local to the function `randarray`.  If you have a large matrix in which this is repeatedly called, this will be faster than a global lookup for that function.

The list comprehension is essentially saying:

```
for each row:
    for each column:
        <random integer>
```

Note that `randint()` is inclusive on both ends.

If you really need optimization, look into `itertools.repeat()`.